# pluralize without count number in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, pluralize

I am building a blog app.  I'd like to be able to pluralize the word "article" if more than one "post" is "published."

Like so:
Available Articles
or
Available Article

This is what I have....

```
 Available <%=  pluralize @posts.published, "Article" %>:
```

I've tried

```
 Available <%=  pluralize @posts.published.count, "Article" %>:
```

and that works...but I don't want the number.  It shouldn't read Available 5 Articles....it should have no number.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I have been looking for the answer to this myself and wasn't satisfied with any of the existing ones. Here's the tidiest solution I found:

```
 Available <%=  "Article".pluralize(@posts.published.count) %>:
```

Documentation is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-pluralize). Relevant bits:

> Returns the plural form of the word in the string.
>
> ```
> If the optional parameter count is specified,
> the singular form will be returned if count == 1.
> For any other value of count the plural will be returned.
>
>   'post'.pluralize             # => "posts"
>   'apple'.pluralize(1)         # => "apple"
>   'apple'.pluralize(2)         # => "apples"
> ```

Comment: Its only works to english language!
In portuguese we have other pluralize forms. So its do not the best answer.

Comment: @JonatasTeixeira you can pass in the locale as the 2nd param.

Answer (score 13):

You could use [Rails Internationalization (I18n)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization) to accomplish this. In your `config/data/en.yml` your translations would be something like this:

```
en:
  available_articles:
    zero: Available Article
    one: Available Article
    other: Available Articles
```

And in your view you should be able to get the translation like this:

```
<%= t(:available_articles, count: @posts.published.count) %>
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to doing this over Hetal Khunti's answer?  I'd like to accept your answer, because I wanted an alternative to Hetal's...but if the alternative is less clean I'd like to know (

Comment: Well, I'd say that this approach leads to a much more readable view, but the project I'm working on has everything localized so this is what I'm used to see. Another benefit of this way is that if you want to change the wording when the count is zero, that is fairly simple.

Comment: Great Jakob.. New thing to learn.. 1+ for this other solution `Rails Internationalization (I18n)`

Comment: I have this in my view `<%= I18n.t('items', count: @size) %>  
` and `en:
  items:
    zero: no items
    one: one item
    other: %{count} items` in my en.yml. 

I get an error **found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 26 column 12>**

Comment: @Suraj You can't start the translation with a '%' character, so just wrap it in quotes, i.e. `other: "%{count} items"`

Comment: Yeah, did it that way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I did that way I liked so much:

```
- if @post.comments.persisted.any?
    h4
      = t(:available_comments, count: @post.comments.count)
    = render @post.comments.persisted
  - else
    p
      | There are no comments for this post.
en:
  available_comments:
    one: "%{count} Comment"
    other: "%{count} Comments"
```

Thank's @Jakob W!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<%= @posts.published.count > 0 ? "Available Article".pluralize(@posts.published.count) : nil %>:`

Comment: That pluralizes regardless of whether or not the count is plural.

Comment: It's working for me. Verify that `@posts.published.count` gives you the number you expect.

Comment: It works fine for a count of "1" or "many"...but if the count is "0" it pluralizes.

Comment: See my updates. I thought you did not want the count to be displayed. This assumes that if the count is 0 or less then nothing should be displayed.

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere What do you want to display if the count is 0?

Comment: Ah....I see why this does this!  I'd like it to say "Available Article" when the count is zero.  I see jljohnstone was trying to help me with hiding it if it was zero...but that's not what I need. I should have mentioned that, as showing a singular word with a count of zero is a bit unusual. @JakobW

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere I posted an answer, please let me know if it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found this pluralize has one bug

```
"user".pluralize(1) => "user"
"user".pluralize(2) => "users"
```

but

```
"user".pluralize(0) => "users"
```

Comment: What's the bug? Do you think it should it be "zero user" not "zero users"?

Answer (score -1):

How about this simple logic? I guess you want to display the number of Article as well if not then simply remove `<%= @posts.published.count %>`

```
Available <%= @posts.published.count %> 
    <% if @posts.published.count > 1 %>
        Articles
    <% else %>
        Article
    <% end %>
```

**OR**

you can use  [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation),

```
Available <%= @posts.published.count %> <%= if (@posts.published.count > 1) ? "Articles" : "Article" %>
```

Output:

```
=> Available 1 Article   # if there is only one article 
=> Available 2 Articles   # if there is more then 1 articles
```

Comment: Yes,  I was using this...but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to write it using rails helpers...etc.  Thanks.  If I don't that way, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere : Yes you can use ternary operator `?:` also for single line condition. `condition? true part : false part`

Comment: This needs to be adjusted to account for the fact that English uses the plural form of nouns for zero number "Available 0 Articles". Easy enough to fix. `<% if count == 1 %>Article<% else %>Articles<% end %>`